# Grub rescue prompt after Ubuntu 19.04 installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I have been trying to install 19.04. After installation I ended up with grub rescue prompt. Tried to fix using boot-repair. But couldn't fix the issue. Can someone please take a look at this:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HMZBpm35NN/

Any pointer in the above is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your grub config points to /dev/sda5, your installation is on that partition?

Comment: I am not sure. I have Linux mint and Ubuntu 19.04 installed in two partitions. Probably sda5 and 3?

Comment: Checking again the configuration it seems that you install Mint after Ubuntu.

Comment: Nope, Mint was installed way back Ubuntu 19.04. And it was all good. The new installation messed it up somehow. Anyway can someone please give some pointer in the above?